# Network interface alias disappearing after reboot. Centos 7

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface

I have a VPS with 2 IP addresses.
If I restart the VPS the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` looks like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=X.X.X.X
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
GATEWAY=X.X.X.X
```

I've tried adding this to eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=X.X.X.X
IPADDR2=Y.Y.Y.Y
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
NETMASK2=255.255.255.192
GATEWAY=X.X.X.X
GATEWAY2=X.X.X.X
```

and also tried creating a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1` that looks like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=Y.Y.Y.Y
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
GATEWAY=X.X.X.X
```

but after rebooting the VPS the ifcfg-eth0 file is reset and the ifcfg-eth0:1 file deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure if this was the case, after a "hard reset" as the VPS company calls it, the alias file `ifcfg-eth0:0` reappeared and I had my second IP again.

I don't know if it was because of some kind of freeze on the hosting company end or if it was because I was trying `0:1` instead of `0:0`.

But this is what fixed it.